# How can I get the pitch of an audio using Librosa? (NOT 2D array, but similar with crepe)

Tags: python, audio, frequency, pitch

Currently, I'm looking for python packages for audio pitch detection (f0 frequency). 
I have found a library called [librosa](https://github.com/librosa/librosa) and tried the *piptrack* function to track pitch. However, the result is a 2D array (shown as below) instead of a 1D array.

[librosa result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNCza.png)

The thing is, I want to get a simple line chart describing the pitch of audio (just like other packages such as [crepe](https://github.com/marl/crepe), [aubio](https://github.com/aubio/aubio), and [parselmouth](https://parselmouth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)).

So how can I get a similar result using librosa?

Here is the code:

```
import librosa
import librosa.display
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

audio_path = 'test.wav'
y, sr = librosa.load(audio_path, sr=None)
pitches, magnitudes = librosa.piptrack(y=y, sr=sr)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.tile(np.arange(pitches.shape[1]), [100, 1]).T, 
pitches[:100, :].T, '.')
plt.xlabel('samples', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('pitch (Hz)', fontsize=18)
plt.savefig("pitch_array_by_fps.png")
```

Comment: Just add the code. Please check my updates. Thanks a lot!